# Изменение массива с помощью массива индексов

Tags: python, массивы, numpy

Есть два массива: один *массив индексов*, другой — *массив элементов*.

Хочу в *массиве элементов* изменить элементы (к примеру, вычесть 1), которые соответствуют индексам, находящимися в *массиве индексов* (без циклов).

К примеру (на вычитание 1):

Исходные данные:

```py
array1 = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [10, 11, 12, 13]], indexes = [[1], [3]]
```

Ожидаемый результат:

```py
array1 = [[1, 1, 3, 4], [10, 11, 12, 12]]
```

Comment: `map()` + `itemgetter()` не подойдёт?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [113]: a1 = np.array(array1)

In [114]: idx = np.array(indexes).ravel()

In [115]: a1
Out[115]:
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [10, 11, 12, 13]])

In [116]: idx
Out[116]: array([1, 3])
```

решение:

```
In [117]: a1[np.arange(len(idx)), idx] -= 1
```

результат:

```
In [118]: a1
Out[118]:
array([[ 1,  1,  3,  4],
       [10, 11, 12, 12]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Если в образовательных целях установлено искусственное ограничение не использовать конструкции `for`, `while`, то можно сделать так:

```
array1 = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [10, 11, 12, 13]]
indexes = [[1, 2], [2, 3]] # добавил индексов для наглядности

list(map(lambda tup: list(map(lambda idx: tup[0].__setitem__(idx, tup[0][idx] - 1), tup[1])), zip(array1, indexes)))

print(array1)
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 1, 2, 4], [10, 11, 11, 12]]
```

**Читаемая версия**

```
list(map(
            lambda tup: list(map(   # tup - кортеж вида: (значения, индексы), полученный
                                    # с помощью zip()
                                    # tup[0] - список со значениями, которые нужно изменить
                                    lambda idx: tup[0].__setitem__(idx, tup[0][idx] - 1),
                                    tup[1] # список с индексами
                                )
                            ),
            zip(array1, indexes)
        )
    )
```

Но конечно, с циклом намного проще:

```
for lst, idxs in zip(array1, indexes):
    for i in idxs:
        lst[i] -= 1
```